# php foreach wrap every 2 divs

Tags: php, foreach

I need to wrap every 2 divs with another div for a project (a row) so it will look like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div> Item </div>
  <div> Item </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div> Item </div>
  <div> Item </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a few solutions but they dont work since the items coming in are odd (9 items). Here is what I had:

```
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach ($contents as $content) 
{
    //var_dump($content);
    $books      = $content["tags"];
    $book_image = $content['content_image'];
    $book_desc  = $content['content_social_description'];

    ++$count;

    if($count == 1)
    {  
        echo "<div class='et_pb_row'>";
    }

    foreach ($books as $book) 
    {
        $book_name      = $book['tag_name'];
        $book_name_trim = str_replace(' ', '-', $book_name);
        ?>
        <!-- Inside the Book Loop -->
        <div class='et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_2 books' style="background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/crowdhubproverbs31/<?php echo $book_image ;?>');">
            <h2><?php echo $book_name; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $book_desc; ?></p>
            <?php echo $count; ?>
        </div>

        <?php

    }

    if ($count == 2)
    {
        echo "</div>";
        $count = 0;
     }
}
?>
```

This works except the second to last row has 3 items even though it dispays the "count" as 2 when I echo it out so it should reset but doesnt. So its:

```
<div class="row">
  <div> Item </div> "Count 1"
  <div> Item </div> "Count 2"
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div> Item </div> "Count 1"
  <div> Item </div> "Count 2"
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div> Item </div> "Count 1"
  <div> Item </div> "Count 2"
  <div> Item </div> "Count 2"
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div> Item </div> "Count 1"
  <div> Item </div> "Count 2"
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have 3 items? It looks to me that your last item does not have a closing div. Since it only has just an opening div, maybe it just looks strange.

Comment: You are manipulating the $count variable on the main loop, meaning that every 2 $content items it will make a new row. If there are N $books in a $content then it will print N times the same $count value and will not make new rows. Do you have two books on the content that's printing 2 twice?

Comment: It works fine but the 3rd Row. All rows are closing correctly. The first 2 rows have 2 items, the 3rd has 3 items, the 4th item has 2 items.

Comment: Why don't you post the actual output of your code instead of that sample? It would be much easier to compare code and output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open and close your `<rows/>` in the books loop, and add a late check for odd books:

```
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach ($contents as $content) 
{
    //var_dump($content);
    $books      = $content["tags"];
    $book_image = $content['content_image'];
    $book_desc  = $content['content_social_description'];


    foreach ($books as $book) 
    {
        ++$count;
        if($count == 1)
        {  
            echo "<div class='et_pb_row'>";
        }
        $book_name      = $book['tag_name'];
        $book_name_trim = str_replace(' ', '-', $book_name);
        ?>
        <!-- Inside the Book Loop -->
        <div class='et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_2 books' style="background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/crowdhubproverbs31/<?php echo $book_image ;?>');">
            <h2><?php echo $book_name; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $book_desc; ?></p>
            <?php echo $count; ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        if ($count == 2)
        {
            echo "</div>";
            $count = 0;
        }


    }
}

if ($count > 0)
{
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Doing so, your `$count` variable will be incremented only when `foreach($books AS $book)` loop is run (thus you have at least one book to print)

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) :

```
//First make a generator to get all books
function allBooks($contents) {
    foreach($contents as $content) {    
        foreach($content['tags'] as $book) {
            yield $book; //Here you can yield whatever you want !
        }
    }
}

//Then create rows
$itemPerRow = 2;
$rows = array_chunk(iterator_to_array(allBooks($contents)), $itemPerRow, true);

//Display all 
foreach($rows as $row) {
   echo '<row>';
      foreach($row as $book) {
         //Display the book !
      }
   echo '</row>';
}
```

Comment: With that code, 2 $books array with 5 items each, will output in 6 `<row>`instead of just 5

Comment: It's Normal !! the last row will have one item. That's what you mean !!

Comment: I see what you mean I've updated the code ;) . Maybe expensive but elegant !